# Submitting form data to MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have searched the forums and also the internet for a solution and I cannot find one. I have an HTML form that I would like to submit to a database, which is already built. Here is the HTML form.

```
<form method="POST" action="form-actions/form-add-center.php" id="add-center">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="large-4 columns">
              <label>Center Name
                <input type="text" id="centerName" name="centerName" />
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="large-4 columns">
              <label>Center Director
                <input type="text" id="centerDirector" name="centerDirector" />
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="large-4 columns">
              <label>Center Type</label>
              <select name="centerType">
                  <optgroup id="centerType">
                        <option value="men">Men's Center</option>
                        <option value="men">Women's Center</option>
                        <option value="men">Boy's Home</option>
                        <option value="men">Girl's Home</option>
                        <option value="men">Hope Outreach</option>
                  </optgroup>
                </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Address</legend>
            <div class="large-12 columns">
              <label>Street
                <input type="text" id="street" name="street" />
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="large-4 columns">
                <label>City
                <input type="text" id="city" name="city" />
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="large-4 columns">
                <label>State</label>
                <select name="physicalState">
                    <optgroup id="physicalState">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                    </optgroup>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="large-4 columns">
                <label>Zip Code
                    <input type="number" id="zip" name="zip" />
                </label>
            </div>
            </fieldset>
            </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="large-4 columns">
                        <label>Phone Number
                            <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" />
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="large-4 columns">
                    <label>Fax Number
                        <input type="text" id="fax" name="fax" />
                    </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">
                    <input type="submit" class="button success" value="Clear Form" onclick="clearForm()">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

And here is the PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {

    $submit         = $_POST['Add'];
    $centerName     = $_POST['centerName'];
    $centerType     = $_POST['centerType'];
    $centerDirector = $_POST['centerDirector'];
    $street         = $_POST['street'];
    $city           = $_POST['city'];
    $state          = $_POST['state'];
    $zip            = $_POST['zip'];
    $phone          = $_POST['phone'];
    $fax            = $_POST['fax'];

    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'someuser';
    $dbpass = 'somepassword';
    $conn   = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if (!$conn) {
        die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO     centers (center_name, center_type, director, street, city, state, zip, phone, fax)
                  VALUES('$centerName','$centerType','$centerDirector','$street','$city','$state','$zip','$phone','$fax')";

    mysql_select_db('elp');
    $retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
    if (!$retval) {
        die('Could not enter data: '.mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Entered data successfully\n";
    mysql_close($conn);
} else {
    echo "Something went wrong...";
}

?>
```

I am getting "Something went wrong..." when I submit the data, per the `else` statement in my PHP. Any help that you can afford would be great!

Comment: I don't see any input with the name `add` in there

Comment: ^^ Same. Why would you be able to retrieve any input named add if there is none in your form? Try changing the test to "CenterAdd" or whatever.

Comment: use mysqli_* functions. usage of mysql_* functions not recommended.

Comment: You should also be wary of the fact that you're testing for $_POST['add'] in the IF statement, and then assigning the value of $submit to be $_POST['Add'] just below it, keep case sensitivity in mind!

Comment: You probably meant to do `<input **name="add"** type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">`, based on `$submit = $_POST['Add'];`, althought that should also be `$submit = $_POST['add'];` ie. lowercase `add`.

Comment: Thank you for the head's up! I can't believe that I did not see that. I removed it and it is saying that I have some SQL syntax errors now, but hopefully I can fix those and move forward. I appreciate both of your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed name "add" in submit input.

```
 <input type="submit" class="button" name="add" value="Submit">
```

Then use

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['add'])) {

$submit   = $_POST['add'];
```

Thanks